# SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'fileapi.domain.org' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

Tags: flutter

I am using FadeInIMage.memoryNetwork and I got the following error in production. We never found this issue in our phone. But it is record by firebase crashlytics. We have verified that all of our image url are working.

Noted: We have used CachedNetwokImage before because of this error. May I know how I can cached this error?

```
FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: widget.imageUrl,
                  placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                  imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                    return Container(color: Colors.grey);
                  },
                )
```

Error

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'fileapi.domain.org' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7). Error thrown Instance of 'ErrorDescription'.
       at _HttpClient.getUrl(_HttpClient.java)
       at NetworkImage._loadAsync(_network_image_io.dart:86)
       at NetworkImage.load(_network_image_io.dart:49)
       at ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<fn>(image_provider.dart:488)
       at ImageCache.putIfAbsent(image_cache.dart:379)
       at ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey(image_provider.dart:486)
       at ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey(scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:106)
       at ImageProvider.resolve.<fn>(image_provider.dart:333)
       at ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<fn>(image_provider.dart:448)
       at SynchronousFuture.then(synchronous_future.dart:41)
       at ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey(image_provider.dart:445)
       at ImageProvider.resolve(image_provider.dart:330)
       at _ImageState._resolveImage(image.dart:1119)
       at _ImageState.didUpdateWidget(image.dart:1091)
       at StatefulElement.update(framework.dart:4992)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update(framework.dart:6222)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at ComponentElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4832)
       at StatefulElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4977)
       at Element.rebuild(framework.dart:4529)
       at StatefulElement.update(framework.dart:5009)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update(framework.dart:6222)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update(framework.dart:6222)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update(framework.dart:6222)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at ComponentElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4832)
       at Element.rebuild(framework.dart:4529)
       at StatelessElement.update(framework.dart:4883)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update(framework.dart:6222)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at ComponentElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4832)
       at StatefulElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4977)
       at Element.rebuild(framework.dart:4529)
       at StatefulElement.update(framework.dart:5009)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at ComponentElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4832)
       at StatefulElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4977)
       at Element.rebuild(framework.dart:4529)
       at StatefulElement.update(framework.dart:5009)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update(framework.dart:6222)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update(framework.dart:6222)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at ComponentElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4832)
       at Element.rebuild(framework.dart:4529)
       at StatelessElement.update(framework.dart:4883)
       at Element.updateChild(framework.dart:3530)
       at ComponentElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4832)
       at StatefulElement.performRebuild(framework.dart:4977)
       at Element.rebuild(framework.dart:4529)
       at BuildOwner.buildScope(framework.dart:2659)
       at WidgetsBinding.drawFrame(binding.dart:891)
       at RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback(binding.dart:370)
       at SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback(binding.dart:1146)
       at SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame(binding.dart:1083)
       at SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame(binding.dart:997)
```

Comment: This error may also occur when user doesn't have internet connectivity and try to fetch the image from the server.

Comment: Yes, properly but it is record so many crash.